# ExtJS 6.0.1 disable cell selection

Tags: javascript, extjs, grid

I'm trying to disable the cell selection in my Ext.grid.Panel.
I found out there are few selectionTypes and selectionModes, but neither worked for me. Would be great if I could achieve this by using the framework.

Thanks in advance.

Update to my question: I want to select a row, but not a single column. Is it possible to disable the cell selection, but allow the user to select the row?

---

### Update

I found a better solution than the suggested ones:

Just use the [theme-variable of the component](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1/classic/Ext.view.Table.html#css_var-S-$grid-row-cell-focus-border-width). 
By setting the value to 0px, the selection disappears completely.

Comment: what condition is set to cancel of selection of a certain cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a list or a tree i usually use row selected event to do what i've to and on cell click i set change selected cell css to nothing.

possibilities:

1. change css of selected cell to null
2. not use cell selected event but rowselected (cell/row selected Always match same)--> if the problem is the cell css when clicked change it

Only workarounds, you can't disable cell click, because without this the rowclick event can't be fired

Comment: Thank you! I'll give it a try.

Comment: add the code to your question if the problem isn't solved, i'll take a view

Answer (score 0):

Have you searched the docs? For "disable", "cell" and "selection", maybe?

Because [`disableSelection:true`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-cfg-disableSelection) works for me.

Comment: Of course I've searched the docs.
But I didnt found this configuration property. Can you provide a link to it? Btw: I'm using ExtJS 6.0.1 (Updated in my question)

Comment: `disableSelection: true` disables selection for the entire grid, not a specific cell.

Answer (score 0):

Override following css classes:

```
.x-grid-item-focused .x-grid-cell-inner:before {     
    border: none; 
}
```

After this, when you select grid cell, the cell selection border won't be displayed.